# Mocking Async HTTP Calls with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, okhttp

I'm using OkHTTP to make async HTTP calls and am trying to use Mockito to mock the behavior:

Here's a shortened version of the source:

```java
okHttpClient
  .newCall(<some Request object>)
  .enqueue(<some Callback object>);
```

Here's how I'm trying to mock this behavior:

```java
OkHttpClient httpClientMock = mock(OkHttpClient.class, Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

doAnswer(invocation -> {
  ((Callback) invocation.getArgument(0)).onResponse(remoteResponse);
  return null;
}).when(httpClientMock).newCall(any(Request.class)).enqueue(any(Callback.class));
```

But when I run my tests I am getting a NullPointerException and an InvalidUseOfMatchersException. When I read through the instructions in the InvalidUseOfMatchersExceptions, I noticed that the pattern I'm using is pretty close to one of the ones they suggest:

`doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, my experience with Mockito is fairly limited.

Comment: Try putting all the deepcalls in the same `when()` as demonstrated here:
https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-fluent-apis

Comment: That results in a design-time error "no instance(s) of type variables(s) T exists so that void conforms to T." `when(...).thenReturn()` and `doAnswer(...).when(...)` are different.

Comment: A word of advice, mocking classes you don't own is a known bad practice that has the potential of making tests very hard to maintain.

Comment: @Augusto I read up a bit on that and it made me realize I likely have a poor design to begin with and need another layer of misdirection. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @jerney Happy to be of help! If you want to read a bit more about how to use mocks properly, I suggest you to get a copy of *Growing Object-Oriented Software guided by tests*. It's a fantastic book and is packed with good practices about design and testing.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 method calls, one is newCall which returns a Call object and then there is enqueue method which returns void. I think you should have a mock for Call as well.

```
 Call mockCall = mock(Call.class); // Creating a mock for Call class

 doReturn(mockCall).when(httpClientMock).newCall(any(Request.class)); // The mock call object is returned on newCall method invocation

 doAnswer(invocation -> {
  ((Callback) invocation.getArgument(0)).onResponse(remoteResponse);
  return null;
}).when(mockCall).enqueue(any(Callback.class));
```